# Tcl Switch case error ,I need proper explanation for the error

Tags: switch-statement, syntax-error, tcl

Kindly help me detecting the error in the following code

```
proc strcmp { d1 d2 } {
    set res [string compare $d1 $d2]

    switch $res  
    0 {
    puts "String is equal "
    } 
    1 {
    puts "$d1 > $d2"
    } default { 
    puts "$d2 > $d1"
    }

}
```

I get this error message when i try to execute in tcl 8.5

```
wrong # args: should be "switch ?switches? string pattern body ... ?default body?"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the "0" on a different line. Tcl treats newlines as command terminators. You're probably seeing an error like "0: no such command"

Use either line continuations

```
switch $res  \
0 {
    puts "String is equal "
} \
1 {
    puts "$d1 > $d2"
} \
default { 
    puts "$d2 > $d1"
}
```

or enclosing brackets (good for readability)

```
switch $res  {
    0 {
        puts "String is equal "
    } 
    1 {
        puts "$d1 > $d2"
    } 
    default { 
        puts "$d2 > $d1"
    }
}
```

Docs:

- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm (rules 1 and 9)
- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/switch.htm

Comment: He won't be seeing an error about the `0` command not existing because he's hitting the error about not enough arguments to `switch` first…

Answer (score 0):

The exact error I got when I tried to run your code was:

> bad option `"-1"`: must be `-exact`, `-glob`, `-regexp`, or `--` while executing

The [Tcl docs for switch](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm) mention these commands: they tell the switch how to match the arguments. Adding `-exact --` before `$res` at the start of the switch statement seems to make it work:

```
proc strcmp { d1 d2 } {
    set res [string compare $d1 $d2]

    switch -exact -- $res  {
        0 {
            puts "String is equal "
        } 
        1 {
            puts "$d1 > $d2"
        } 
        default { 
            puts "$d2 > $d1"
        }
    }

}

strcmp "world" "hello"
strcmp "hello" "hello"
strcmp "hello" "world"
```

(You could drop the `-exact` if you want, as it's the default – I only include it so you can see where to put in another option.)

This gives the following output ([codepad example](http://codepad.org/ukOov6GW)):

```
world > hello
String is equal 
world > hello
```

so for some reason, `-1` (the return code from `string compare` for the third example) is getting matched to `1` by the switch statement. I don't know enough Tcl to know why that might be the case – you could consider asking that as a different question.